# Use 64bit code on a 32bit machine

Tags: cpu, x86-64, translate, qemu, x86

I have a stupid question:
Is it possible to convert a x86_64 application to a 32bit one?
I mean, for example, as Qemu can emulate a 64bit processor (on a 32bit machine),
and can run the linux kernel for that arch, is possible to dump in some way the full data and collect it in order to make a translated code which work as the first
(by running the same on a 32bit machine ) ??

Comment: The closest you will get is as you said Qemu, the ABIs are fundamentally different and there is no way to magically convert. Second, why do you actually want to do this? What the the problem you are trying to solve or is this just educational? (not to say conversion is impossible by the way, just that it will be an unbelievably manual, time consuming task)

Comment: Your best bet would be to run the program through a decompiler, then you would have to read through the codebase and manually tweak the code until it will compile onto the 32 bit arch then build it for that. However unless you are an expert reverse engineer (and to some degree even then) this will be immensely time consuming and error prone for anything but the most trivial program. Also, +1 for being bold enough to ask. Have a look at this if you are interested http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation

Comment: My goal was to run a different-arch code on a machine, and let it work as it was build to, and to run it's own applications without varying them

Comment: Ah, if that is the case and you are looking for an automatic process you should really stick with Qemu, it can achieve 66% or so of original performance in many cases and is simple with few caveats.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for an automatic process like qemu(is like that but), I'm looking for a process or something which is capable to alter the code, and produce a reusable one

Comment: To get "good" performance will require a lot of work.  You will have to translate not just your application, but all the libraries it links to.  You will have to emulate the kernel calls, translating 64-bit O/S calls to a 32-bit O/S.  You will have to emulate an application address space that is in the Terabytes in an address space that is in the Gigabytes.  Depending on the working set size of the application it might end up thrashing/paging to disk trying to emulate the larger address space.  Not worth doing.